# The cast to value type 'System.Single' failed in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I execute this query on my data  :

```
 newObj.TotalSizeDone =
         _ctx.TestPackages.Where(
             i =>
                 i.LineCheckState && i.TestState && i.Flushing && i.Drying && i.ReInstatement &&
                 i.CleaningState).Sum(i=>i.Size);
```

But i get this error :

> The cast to value type 'System.Single' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

My class:

```
public int Id { set; get; }
public string PackageNumber { set; get; }
public float Size { set; get; }

public string Descrption { set; get; }
public DateTime SubmitDateTime { set; get; }
public string TestPackageLocation { set; get; }
public string TestPackageOrder { set; get; }

public string LineCheckReportNumber { set; get; }
public bool LineCheckState { set; get; }
public DateTime? LineCheckSubmitDateTime { set; get; }

public string CleanReportNumber { set; get; }
public bool CleaningState { set; get; }//ndt test
public DateTime? CleanSubmitDateTime { set; get; }

public string TestReportNumber { set; get; }
public bool TestState { set; get; }
public DateTime? TestSubmitDateTime { set; get; }

public string DryingReportNumber { set; get; }
public bool Drying { set; get; }
public DateTime? DryingSubmitDateTime { set; get; }

public string FlushingReportNumber { set; get; }
public bool Flushing { set; get; }
public DateTime? FlushingSubmitDateTime { set; get; }

public string ReInstatementReportNumber { set; get; }
public DateTime? ReInstatementSubmitDateTime { set; get; }
public bool ReInstatement { set; get; }
```

The data :

```
INSERT [dbo].[TestPackages] ([Id], [PackageNumber], [Size], [Descrption], [SubmitDateTime], [TestPackageLocation], [TestPackageOrder], [LineCheckReportNumber], [LineCheckState], [LineCheckSubmitDateTime], [CleanReportNumber], [CleaningState], [CleanSubmitDateTime], [TestReportNumber], [TestState], [TestSubmitDateTime], [DryingReportNumber], [Drying], [DryingSubmitDateTime], [FlushingReportNumber], [Flushing], [FlushingSubmitDateTime], [ReInstatementReportNumber], [ReInstatementSubmitDateTime], [ReInstatement]) VALUES (1, N'TestPackage-5185', 0, N'323', CAST(0x0000A658016AB9A6 AS DateTime), N'1220', N'1', N'256', 1, CAST(0x0000A66300000000 AS DateTime), N'15', 1, NULL, N'2626', 1, CAST(0x0000A66A00000000 AS DateTime), N'150', 1, CAST(0x0000A65800000000 AS DateTime), N'21', 1, CAST(0x0000A66300000000 AS DateTime), N'212', CAST(0x0000A66300000000 AS DateTime), 0)
GO
```

Comment: Are all these properties boolean?

Comment: What are the types of `TestPackages` and `TestPackages.Size` and `totalSizeDone`?

Comment: I added the class to the post

Comment: @musefan i add the data ,but just one of my datetime is null

Comment: @musefan i just have one record in my database

Comment: Does that record have a Size that is NULL, perhaps?

Comment: @musefan no the value of size in my record is zero

Comment: Try `Sum(i=>(float?)i.Size) ?? 0f` and see if that works.

Comment: @Dennis_E it works :Sum(i => (float?)i.Size) ?? 0f

Comment: @Dennis_E thank you

Comment: @EhsanAkbar No problem, but I just googled the error message, which led me to the duplicate question, which provided the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is caused because you do not have any data that matches the `where` clause logic (in this case `ReInstatement` is `false`), this means that zero results are returned.

When performing a `Sum` on no results, it will want to use a `null` result but the return type of `Sum` will be expecting to match your `float` type (so it fails).

In order to be able to `Sum` when no results exist, you can make use of the `DefaultIfEmpty` function as follows, which means there will never be any `null` values for `Sum` to worry about:

```
var results = _ctx.TestPackages.Where( i => i.LineCheckState && 
                                            i.TestState && 
                                            i.Flushing && 
                                            i.Drying && 
                                            i.ReInstatement && 
                                            i.CleaningState);

// Sum the results, and in the event of a null value, assign 0f instead.
newObj.TotalSizeDone = results.Select(i => i.Size)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty(0f)
                            .Sum();
```

Alternatively, you can use the following so that `Sum` will know to return a nullable type (which can then be coalesced with `??`):

```
newObj.TotalSizeDone = results.Sum(i => (float?)i.Size) ?? 0f;
```

Comment: Won't the 1st option execute the query twice?

Comment: Error CS0019 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'int'